# How to get ARM AVDs working in Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
ERROR   | This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.
ERROR   | ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

(`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` *is* defined, and when things are running properly it doesn't complain about this)

After copying `Android/Sdk/system-images/android-10/default/x86/kernel-ranchu` into `~/.android/avd/2.7_QVGA_API_3.avd` the emulator is able to open, but nothing renders, presumably because of error `resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8`.

I have tested ARM builds of newer versions of Android, and those don't work either. But I'm not bothered about them, as x86 builds are available for Gingerbread and Ice Cream Sandwich onwards. I'm interested in running Cupcake or Donut, or even 1.0 or 1.1 if that's possible, but Eclair/Froyo/Honeycomb would be a nice bonus too.

I'm aware old versions of Android can't access the Play Store or use modern libraries, and have a market share of approximately 0%, so informing me of this isn't helpful.